# Converting Matrix into an array

Tags: matlab, indexing, reshape, dimension

I have a matrix that is `size(A) = 20x301088` and another vector `linear_index` which is `301088x1`.
I need to convert `A` into an array that is `97x97x32x20`.  But it has to be in a certain order, the vector `linear_index` contains the linear indices of a `97x97x32` in a specific order.

For example, the element at `A(20,4)` should be put into `linear_index(4)` of `B(:,:,:,20)`. Hopefully that makes sense. Each row of `A` will make its own `97x97x32` matrix, and the elements will be placed at the indices specified by the value in `linear_index`.

I have done it once but it requires the `shiftdim` command:

```
B(1:length(lx) , linear_index) = A(1:length(lx) , :);
B = shiftdim(A,1);
```

This works, but the `shiftdim` command takes a bit of time, especially as the size of my matrices can go up to `97x97x32x194`.

Comment: what is it about? Matlab, Octave? You should clearly indicate that with an appropriate tag

Comment: My apologies, this is my first time using this website.Thanks. It is Matlab, but I already figured out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
>> B = A(:,linear_index)'; %' re-order  and permute
>> B = reshape( B, 97, 97, 32, 194, 20 );
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it working using this

A(linear_index,:) = A(1:length(linear_index),:);
B = reshape(A , [97 97 32 20]);

Probably something similar to what you wrote.

Comment: @RossAnthonyDiJulio so `linear_index` is a reverse map... nice